# Jquery submission on two forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two forms, one one is validated it hides and shows the next form, then submits.
However by doing this, it only posts one forms variables.

I came up with one solution to input form one inputs into hidden inputs in form2, but i'm wondering if there's a better solution as ill be adding loads more inputs eventually.

Html:

```
<div name="div1" style="display:block;">
<label>Div1</label>
    <form name="form1" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="testa">
        <input type="text" name="testb">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<div name="div2" style="display:none;">
<label>Div2</label>
    <form name="form2" method="post">
        <input type="" name="testa">
        <input type="" name="testb">
        <input type="text" name="testc">
        <input type="text" name="testd">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form[name='form1']").validate({
    rules: {
      testa: "required",
      testb: "required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //form.submit();
        alert('Going to next step...');
        var value1 = $('input[name="testa"]').val();
        var value2 = $('input[name="testb"]').val();
        $('input[name="testa"]').val(value1);
        $('input[name="testb"]').val(value2);
        $('[name="div1"]').hide();
        $('[name="div2"]').show();
        return false;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form[name='form2']").validate({
    rules: {
      testc: "required",
      testd: "required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Submitting');
        form.submit();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could just have one form with hidden sections that only become visible when appropriate. The use of `<fieldset>` in forms is great, not only for creating sections and managing them as a single unit, but also for accessibility.

Comment: Ahh yes, never crossed my mind will give it a go. Can you validate field sets separately with jquery?

Comment: Please see my working answer below. If elements are not displayed with `display:none` then they do not participate in validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your not using the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) correctly. It needs a `for` attribute that has a value that is the `id` of the form element that the label is "for" or it needs to wrap the element it is for.

Next, `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute. Only form fields that can and will submit their data via form submission can have a `name`.

Also, there is no need for multiple JQuery `document.ready()` handlers. You can place all the code you want run when the document is ready inside of a single `document.ready()`. And speaking of JQuery, unless you need something very specific to the JQuery validation library, regular HTML can do the same thing you are doing but without the JQuery. You could just add the `required` attribute to the required elements.

And, you should not use the same `name` for multiple elements within a form, except in the case of checkboxes and radio buttons as they act as groups of related choices.

As for your main question, just use a single `form` but hide sections of it as needed. It's best to define sections of a form using the `fieldset` element, which also aids in accessibility.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form[name='form']").validate({
    rules: {
      test1a: "required",
      test1b: "required",
      test2a: "required",
      test2b: "required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //form.submit();
        alert('Going to next step...');
        var value1 = $('input[name="testa"]').val();
        var value2 = $('input[name="testb"]').val();
        $('input[name="testa"]').val(value1);
        $('input[name="testb"]').val(value2);
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name="form" method="post">
  <fieldset id="first">
    <legend>First Set of Questions</legend>
        <input type="text" name="test1a">
        <input type="text" name="test1b">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="second" class="hidden">
    <legend>Second Set of Questions</legend>
        <input type="" name="test2a">
        <input type="" name="test2b">
        <input type="text" name="testc">
        <input type="text" name="testd">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Why in the world would this be down voted? Difficiencies in the original question were identified and explained, an alternate way of solving the problem was proposed (which was what the question asked for) and working code provided. Down voter: learn what a down vote is supposed to be used for.